# how to fetch data quickly in join query?

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables users, orders and comments every tables has 10087250,24949600 and 26532000 much records, I made this query to counts comments on every order but it is taking more than half an hour to execute, how to speed up this query.
**Note:** there is already index on foreig_key columns.

```
select users.user_name, orders.id, count(comments.order_id)
  from orders
 inner join users on users.id=orders.user_id
 inner join comments on orders.id=comments.order_id
 group by comments.order_id, users.user_name, orders.id
 limit 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first - probably yuo need ORDER BY clause to use it with LIMIT
If you need most commented pair you can ORDER BY count DESC

The second things comments.order_id = orders.id. Why do you use both for GROUP?

```
group by comments.order_id, users.user_name, orders.id
```

May be you can help something like this:

```
WITH grouped AS (
   SELECT order_id AS id, count(*)
     FROM comments
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 2 DESC
    LIMIT 2
)
SELECT u.user_name, g.id, g.count
  FROM grouped AS g
  JOIN orders AS o ON
       o.id = g.id
  JOIN users AS u ON
       u.id = o.user_id
```

This allows to avoid join all tables before filtering and grouping

Comment: i have already did that to reduce query size but still it is taking around 3min, as i mentioned above into my DB 10087250,24949600 and 26532000 much records exists there respected tables users, orders and comments. Is it problematic for query? or can say how large amount of data support by db in case of MySql and PostgreSQL, can you please suggest or provide some nice tutorial, thanks for help.

Comment: Do you want it for all time?

Comment: In this case probably you need aggregate table or materialized view to look whole data before plust just today direct from table

Comment: Actually i am a ROR programmer so itsn't possible every time when user want to access data from web page we follow that.

Comment: You can refresh your aggregate table by TRIGGER. Mat view view refreshes by command REFRESH VIEW. By using TRIGGER you can select from it without summing. In case with MAT VIEW you cab refresh it once a day. In both cases you need index on summed field BY DESC

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use temporary tables before aggregating the records. This might help to reduce the query time. Something like this...

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table(
...
);

INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT users.user_name, orders.id, comments.order_id
FROM orders INNER JOIN users ON users.id = orders.user_id INNER JOIN comments ON orders.id = comments.order_id;

SELECT user_name, id, count(order_id) FROM temp_table group by order_id, user_name, id;
```

Comment: Won't work, taking lots of time to insert data into temp. table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reduce a unneccessary join between orders and comments tables. All you want to get from table comments is how many comments of an order, so you need to do denormalization.

It means you need to add a `comments_count` column into `orders` table, and when every a comment is added to an order, just increase it or decrease it if a comment of order is deleted.

After you add new `comments_count` column, you need to update `comments_count` for each order.

Then you can just load orders table and you already have comments count for each order.